# make Slick slider last right slide bigger than others

Tags: javascript, html, css, slick.js

I want to create a slick slider that its last item from right be bigger than the others

like the image,[image]

here is a regular slick slider: I want to make this look like the image can anyone help me

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./slick.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./slick-theme.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="scale_slick">
      <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="" /></div>
      <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="" /></div>
      <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="" /></div>
      <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="" /></div>
      <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="" /></div>
      <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="" /></div>
      <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="" /></div>
      <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="" /></div>
      <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="" /></div>
      <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="" /></div>
    </div>

    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script src="./slick.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(".scale_slick").slick({
        slidesToShow: 4,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 5000,
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If it's the active slide you want to make bigger you can use the class `.slick-slide.slick-active` class

Comment: no as the image shows i want the last right slide to be bigger like its show the content

Answer (score 1):

try like this

here slidesToShow: 4 so , try `.slick-active + .slick-active + .slick-active + .slick-active`

```
 .slick-active + .slick-active + .slick-active + .slick-active{
      transform: scale(1.3);
      border: 1px solid rgb(17, 17, 17);
 }
```

**Live demo** :

```css
.slick-active + .slick-active + .slick-active + .slick-active{
  transform: scale(1.3);
  border: 1px solid rgb(17, 17, 17);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.css" integrity="sha512-wR4oNhLBHf7smjy0K4oqzdWumd+r5/+6QO/vDda76MW5iug4PT7v86FoEkySIJft3XA0Ae6axhIvHrqwm793Nw==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.js" integrity="sha512-WNZwVebQjhSxEzwbettGuQgWxbpYdoLf7mH+25A7sfQbbxKeS5SQ9QBf97zOY4nOlwtksgDA/czSTmfj4DUEiQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.css" integrity="sha512-yHknP1/AwR+yx26cB1y0cjvQUMvEa2PFzt1c9LlS4pRQ5NOTZFWbhBig+X9G9eYW/8m0/4OXNx8pxJ6z57x0dw==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="scale_slick">
      <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="" /></div>
      <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="" /></div>
      <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="" /></div>
      <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="" /></div>
      <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="" /></div>
      <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="" /></div>
      <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="" /></div>
      <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="" /></div>
      <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="" /></div>
      <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="" /></div>
    </div>


    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js" integrity="sha512-XtmMtDEcNz2j7ekrtHvOVR4iwwaD6o/FUJe6+Zq+HgcCsk3kj4uSQQR8weQ2QVj1o0Pk6PwYLohm206ZzNfubg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
      $(".scale_slick").slick({
        slidesToShow: 4,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 5000,
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```